# node headers are set however some users experiences Access-control errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a node server that runs the following header code:

```
    app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    // Set custom headers for CORS
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Now on many computers and browsers this works fine (including my own) however someone who is not sitting at my office gets the following error message:

[image]

Okay thats abit hard to read so here it is the two errors:

1. Failed to load resource: Origin `http://angular.mydomain.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://angular.mydomain.com:8080/login`. Origin `http://angular.mydomain.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow_origin.

Can anyone tell me whats going on here??

**Headers**

[image]

The login route:

```
router.route('/login')
.post(function (req, res) {
    var user = User.build();

    var username = req.body.username || '';
    var password = req.body.password || '';

    if (username == '' || password == '') {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({
            "status": 401,
            "message": "Invalid credentials"
        });
        return;
    }
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);


    user.retrieveByNamePassword(username, function (users) {
        var i = 0;
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, users.password)) {
            var log = User_Login.build()
            log.findLastLogin(users.id, function (result) {
                users.last_login = result;
                if (users.user_type_id > 3) {
                    res.json(genToken(users, null));
                }
                else {
                    var div = Division.build();
                    selected_user = users;
                    var root = [selected_user.division_id];
                    div.retrieveByDivisionId(selected_user.division_id, function (division) {
                        var result = [];
                        var root = [division];
                        (function loop() {
                            var element = root[0];
                            var divisions = Division.build();
                            divisions.retrieveByParentId(element.id, function (divisions) {
                                if (divisions) {
                                    divisions.forEach(function (division) {
                                        root.push(division);
                                    });
                                    result.push(element.id);
                                    root.splice(0, 1);
                                    if (root.length > 0) {
                                        loop()
                                    }
                                    else if (root.length == 0) {
                                        res.json(genToken(users, result));
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    res.send(401, "No division found");
                                }
                            });
                        }());
                    })
                }
            }, function (error) {
                var i = 0;
            });

        } else {
            // If authentication fails, we send a 401 back
            res.status(401);
            res.json({
                "status": 401,
                "message": "Invalid credentials"
            });
            return;
        }
    }, function (error) {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({
            "status": 401,
            "message": "Invalid credentials"
        });
        return;
    });
});
```

Comment: Can that person ("someone who is not sitting at my office") confirm what CORS headers they are getting (or not getting) in the Network logger of the browser? Similarly, can you confirm that the server is setting those headers? In particular, I'd want to eliminate the possibility of a proxy somewhere stripping headers.

Comment: @apsillers hang on a minute il get him to send me a screenshot of his networks tab

Comment: @apsillers added headers

Comment: Is your Node code adding `Server: Apache` in the response for some reason? Or is your Node code acting as a proxy for an Apache server? That smells a little like they're not reaching the right server. Do your successful internal responses include that header?

Comment: @apsillers Response is empty

Comment: @apsillers my friend just used a proxy now he does not get the error?

Comment: Can you include the code where you set up the `/login` route?  This looks like express trying to automatically handle an `OPTIONS` request for you.  Note how the headers you've tried to set aren't actually present in the response.

Comment: @AaronDufour added the login route

Comment: @MarcRasmussen And somewhere you're doing something like `app.use(router)` with the `router` that the login route is being attached to?  (The whole definition of `/login` isn't necessary, just the part where you attach it to the router - I know this question is getting a bit long.)

Comment: @AaronDufour Yes i can add that aswell

Comment: @AaronDufour app.use('/', router);

Comment: @AaronDufour As i said not everyone has this problem only a few (not including my self)

Answer (score 0):

maybe he is receiving a 404 or similar code that represents an unreachable resource from this foreign network.

Comment: There are no 400, 404 or 500 response in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of express trying to handle the `OPTIONS` request.  I recommend a fix in the final paragraph, but read through if you want to understand more thoroughly why this is happening.

Why is there an `OPTIONS` request?  That is what's called a "preflight" ([read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)).  Essentially, if the request is cross-origin and looks "dangerous" ("safe" requests are `GET`/`HEAD`/`POST` with no custom headers and one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`/`multipart/form-data`/`text/plain` as the `Content-Type`), the browser first sends an `OPTIONS` request to make sure that the cross-origin request is going to be allowed.  If the right headers are set, it will then send the actual request.

You are attempting to set the right headers in the `app.all` handler, but they're not present in the response.

First, let's take a look at how express processes a request.  It first runs all of the middleware attached to `app` (in the order it was attached).  "Middleware" is anything attached with `app.use`.  Then, it goes through each route, in the order they were attached.  Routes are anything attached with `app.all`, `app.get`, etc.  If any of these steps fail to call `next` (typically because they sent a response), the chain stops.

Since your headers are being set in an `app.all`, they are part of the routing stage.  Since you attach `router` with `app.use`, it is part of the middleware stage.

However, an express router that sees an `OPTIONS` request with a URL matching one of its routes does something special.  If it gets to the end of that router without completing the request, it automatically sends a response with an `Allow` header set.  This is why the request never makes it to your `app.all` route that sets headers.

Suggested fix: Set your headers (and send the response, if the method is `OPTIONS`) in a middleware (`app.use`), not a route.  You must also make sure this middleware is attached before the router that handles `/login`.

So, instead of your `app.all('/*',`, use `app.use('/',`.  Make sure this happens before the `app.use('/', router)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it seems that this might work but what options should i set and where should i do ? :) could you give a code example?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Edited with clearer instructions at the end.  Does that make sense?